# Overriding __getattribute__ for the Model class in Django

Tags: python, django

In Django, I need to create a model in which an instance of that model can inherit values from another instance of that model in what amounts to a superclass-subclass type relationship.  I created a field in this model called parent, which is an optional self-referencing foreign key.  I then want to override the __getattribute__ method as follows:

```
def __getattribute__(self, name):
    if models.Model.__getattribute__(self, 'parent') is None:
        return models.Model.__getattribute__(self, name)
    elif models.Model.__getattribute__(self, name) is not None:
        return models.Model.__getattribute__(self, name)
    else:
        return parent.__getattribute__(name)
```

This code causes an infinite recursion because the __get__ method of the Model class calls the built-in method getattr passing in the instance as the first parameter.

Is there another way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is fraught with difficulty when done this way.

Please reconsider overriding `__getattribute__` and use a plain old properties for this.

I suspect that a simple "getter" with a property names will do eveything you want without bumping into any magic.

Yes, you may have several similar fields, but I think that simple, obvious properties fit better with the Django ORM.

Comment: Fair enough.  I suspected that this was the case.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Do you need that parent's attributes shadow own ones? If not, you'd better overwrite `__getattr__()` instead of `__getattribute__()` which is not called when instance itself has property with this name:

```
def __getattr__(self, name):
    return getattr(self.parent, name)
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that overriding `__getattribute__` or `__getattr__` may lead to performance cost. Probably there is a better way to solve this problem:

1. On model instance initialization, if an inheritable field is empty and corresponding parent's field is not, do `setattr(self, field_name, getattr(self.parent, field_name))`.
2. Keep track of model instance field changes.
3. Before saving the instance, set the fields that were previously overridden but not changed to `None`.

I'm developing a Django app for that: https://github.com/Altaisoft/django-inheritance